# How to have CSS style for specific div?

Tags: html, css

I want to use border radius for specific images, how I can do that in CSS? When I try to use border radius property it applies it on all the images on that page, and when I use it via class it don't work. Please look at this code and tell me.

```css
#radiusimage{
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<img class="radiusimage" src="https://bestforandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/music-apps-1-300x150.png" alt="music-apps" width="300" height="170" />
```

Comment: add another class

Comment: `.` is for class and `#` is for id in CSS.

Answer (score 5):

While you use `class` HTML attribute, you need to use `.` in CSS

```css
.radiusimage {
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<img class="radiusimage" src="https://bestforandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/music-apps-1-300x150.png" alt="music-apps" width="300" height="170" />
```

---

If you want to use `#` in CSS, then change your HTML attribute to `id`

```css
#radiusimage {
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<img id="radiusimage" src="https://bestforandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/music-apps-1-300x150.png" alt="music-apps" width="300" height="170" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Because your `img` tag has no id of `radiusimage` try to use `.` not `#` on radiusimage it specifies its a class.

Answer (score 1):

Your css define radiusimage as a `id` and in HTML use as a class..

```css
#radiusimage{
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<img id="radiusimage" src="https://bestforandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/music-apps-1-300x150.png" alt="music-apps" width="300" height="170" />
```

Or if you want us as class define class in css like this:

```css
.radiusimage{
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<img class="radiusimage" src="https://bestforandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/music-apps-1-300x150.png" alt="music-apps" width="300" height="170" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you using id`(#)` in the place of class`(.)`

Here is solution
    https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/f1j4y8gr/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply this to a number of images, then you should use a class, but add it on as another class if neccessary and remember your unique id

so img id = "apple" class = "green borderradius"
will look different than img id="apple" class ="green" for example

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/4f4f2nqy/) or snippet

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow
}

.radius {
  border-radius: 25px;
}

img {
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img id ="apple" class="yellow radius" src="http://www.hudsonproduce.com/images/fruitimages/apples-fuji.png">

<img id="apple1" class="green radius" src="http://www.hudsonproduce.com/images/fruitimages/apples-fuji.png">

<img id ="apple2" class="green" src="http://www.hudsonproduce.com/images/fruitimages/apples-fuji.png">
```